# Image going out of screen in Bootstrap markup

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap. In the following markup, when the browser window **width** is reduced to minimum, image spills over and not totally 100% visible.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
         <h1 style="display:inline;">Some heading here</h1>
         <img src="http://feedsinsight.com/Content/logo.png" style='height:38px;vertical-align:bottom;float:right;' />
     </div>
</div>
```

How can I fit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use bootstrap's `img-responsive` class with a max-height rather than a fixed height to make the image scale nicely on small screens.

Bootstrap also has a convenience class `pull-right` which you can use instead of apply the float style inline.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
         <h1 style="display:inline;">Some heading here</h1>
         <img class="img-responsive pull-right" src="http://feedsinsight.com/Content/logo.png" style='max-height:38px; vertical-align:bottom;' />
     </div>
</div>
```

Here's a bootply example: http://www.bootply.com/x9KQXFqkGr

Comment: Totally bang on... fixed the issue, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use min-width and max-width or make "height:38px" to height 100%. Using % values is more responsive than specifying pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Use class="img-fluid" this works in Bootstrap 4. It sets max width to 100%. The height of image is set to auto.